# How to create a new copy of a collection in Meteor depending on a url

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am building a magnetic poetry game you can see here

http://test-magnets.meteor.com/

The idea is that the home page is where a bunch of people can collaborate and build some poems together.  There is a mongo collection for the magnets that stores their position on the screen.

This is working great but I am interested in having an option for people to create their own poems that other people can't access.

I have used iron router to generate a url based on the userId. So now i need to build the functionality of creating a private copy of the magnet collection that only that user can use and does not affect the collection used in the colloborate/homepage.

I have some faint ideas of how to do this.

Maybe dynamically generate a new magnet collection with the userId?

Maybe publish and subscribe can handle this?

There might be a package already available for this?

If anyone has any suggestions how to implement this, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Fridge collection and add a FridgeId key to your magnets that references the fridge they belong to. Then configure somewhere that the homepage shows the magnets for the fridge with id 1, and generate a url based on the fridge id for the rest.

That would allow each user to have several fridges or to have fridges where several users can collaborate.

Comment: so would i do something like this to make the association between the 2 collections

var fridgeId = Fridge.insert({
   fridgeId: fridgeId
});

Magnets.insert({
    fridgeId:fridgeId
});

Comment: Mongo already creates an _id field so you don't need to create one for Fridge, the insert method will return this _id: `var fridgeId = Fridges.insert({}); Magnets.insert({fridgeId: fridgeId});`